# Update article hits through Newsflash module?

Tags: module, articles

So, the article hits for an article don't update if the article is viewed via the Newsflash module. Anybody know how to make the article hits increase each time said article is loaded via the Newsflash module? Currently, you have to actually open the article page for the hits to increase, but they won't if the article is just viewed through a Newsflash module.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I check in the code I don't see the module updating article hits any where, but I think article should only be updated its hits when we view full article's detail, so I think this module shouldn't update article hits.

This module calls onContentAfterDisplay and onContentBeforeDisplay events, so you can build a custom plugin to update article hits by catching these events from the module. And yes this requires programming.